# how to fix an equation's error

Tags: equations

I would like to write this equation:
[image]

Having made the following code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\hat{V}(\hat{\beta}_1)= \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \hat{u}_i^2}}{\left( \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)^2 }} \xrightarrow[P]{\text{\textlatin{White se}}} V(\hat{\beta}_1)= \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sigma_i^2}}{\left( \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)^2 }} 
\end{equation*}
```

It shows me

> ! Missing } inserted.  
>                   }

but I can't find where } is missing.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

`\displaystyle` is a declaration and not a command with argument. Your `\displaystyle{...}` opens a group and so `\left(` and `\right)` end up at different grouping levels, which is not allowed.

It should be `{\displaystyle ...}` to limit the scope. However, the numerator and denominator of a fraction act as scope delimiters, so there's no need of additional braces in this case.

I'd not use `\left` and `\right`, however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel} % for \textlatin
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{V}(\hat{\beta}_1)=
\frac
  {\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \hat{u}_i^2}
  {\displaystyle\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\biggr)^2} 
\xrightarrow[P]{\text{\textlatin{White se}}} 
V(\hat{\beta}_1)=
\frac
  {\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sigma_i^2}
  {\displaystyle\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\biggr)^2} 
\end{equation*}
\textlatin{Alternative}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{V}(\hat{\beta}_1)=
\frac
  {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \hat{u}_i^2}
  {\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\Bigr)^2} 
\xrightarrow[P]{\text{\textlatin{White se}}} 
V(\hat{\beta}_1)=
\frac
  {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sigma_i^2}
  {\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\Bigr)^2} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Notice the usage of `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` that are slightly less tall than the parentheses provided by `\left` and `\right`, which in case of summations is appropriate. The `\,` is a refinement in order that the open parenthesis doesn't bump into the subscript.

I added also an alternative version with not so dramatically big summation signs.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your `\displaystyle` groups include the `\right)` but not the `\left(`

```
\begin{equation*}
\hat{V}(\hat{\beta}_1)= \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \hat{u}_i^2}}{\left( \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)^2 } \xrightarrow[P]{\text{\textlatin{White se}}} V(\hat{\beta}_1)= \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sigma_i^2}}{\left( \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)^2 } 
\end{equation*}
```

Actually, `\displaystyle` doesn't take an argument so you can get rid of some of those braces:

```
\begin{equation*}
\hat{V}(\hat{\beta}_1)
    = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \hat{u}_i^2 }
           {\displaystyle \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \right)^2 }
\xrightarrow[P]{\text{\textlatin{White se}}}
V(\hat{\beta}_1)
    = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sigma_i^2 }
           { \displaystyle \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 \right)^2 } 
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Why `\displaystyle{...}`?

Comment: Because without \displaystyle{...} it showed next to \sum whatever it is written above and below it.

Comment: @giannis yes, I now the effect of `\displaystyle`; that's not what I am asking. I am talking about why not `{\displaystyle...}` if grouping is required. `\displaystyle` doesn't take arguments.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Because I was copying what giannis put and fixing the immediate error.  Then I thought about how to make it a bit clearer.